# Read the output of a command(multiple lines)

Tags: bash

I want to read the 'Content-Lenght' of one internet file. To do that i use cURL to retrieve the headers

```
OUTPUT=`curl -I $URL`

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 12 Jan 2014 00:41:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Last-Modified: Sun, 05 Jan 2014 09:41:44 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 553648128
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

but, when i try to print $OUTPUT, i get only the last line.

Comment: FYI, the reason why you're only getting the last line is because you don't quote the variable, so it's split on whitespace and printed on one line. This, together with the fact that CURL outputs the carriage returns from the HTTP response, means that you only end up seeing the last one, even though all the data is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OUTPUT=$(curl -I $URL | grep 'Content-Length')
```

Answer (score 0):

bash

```
curl -I $url | while read -r response
do 
  case "$response" in
    *Content-Length* )
       echo "==> $response"
    ;;
  esac
done
```